# Unable to set a UINavBarController as a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am unable to set a certain tab view to be a UiNavigation controller. The warning I get is:

```
Pushing a navigation controller is not supported
```

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3, *viewController4;
        viewController1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController3 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController4 = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * listNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, listNavController, viewController4, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, listNavController, viewController4, nil];
```

to

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, nil];
```

and keep a reference to the nav controller if needed. I think that would be the right way to do it, but you could also wrap the nav controller in a simple UIViewController. You would want to do this if viewController3 is not guaranteed to be the bottom most VC in your stack at all times.